# How can I disable the default Sharing in Office365 SharePoint and groups withouth removing the share permission?

Tags: site-collection, share, external-users, office-365-groups, sharing

I explain a bit more:

- I know how to do the sharing that I want, so that is not the problem. I want to share using SharePoint groups, with internal and external users. As i said, that is fine for me.

The problem is:

- Collection Sites/Sites and Groups has sharing default options that i need to remove. That way of sharing can be confussing and risky for the user. So I must remove the default sharing options from everywhere.
- Can I disable also the sharing options into the office online programs? (Word online, Excel online...). :(

Can someone help me?

- Other option is to create all the front-end outside SharePoint and use the Microsoft Graph/ SharePoint API. The cost of doing this is clearly higer, would loose functionality (some I might not need)... But this gives me full front-end control... and would avoid the constant SharePoint front-end changes.

Let's focus in the first part, the disabling the default sharing options.

Your feedback about the alternative is also appreciated.

Regards

Edit: If i disable sharing and i do the sharing with elevated privileges, can work? or it wouldn't work because the site doesn't allow sharing?